# Cannot Create Azure AD Application with Azure DevOps + Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create an Azure AD application using terraform along with our Azure DevOps pipeline, but I am getting the following error:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* module.cluster.module.cluster.azuread_application.cluster: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azuread_application.cluster: graphrbac.ApplicationsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2019-02-19T23:22:23","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"<SOME GUID>"}}]
```

I'm pretty sure this is because the pipeline's service principal doesn't have the proper permissions within our Azure AD.

This is the offending Terraform code:

```
resource "azuread_application" "cluster" {
  name = "some-application"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "cluster" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.cluster.application_id}"
}
```

Here is what the Terraform Step Looks like (I'm using a Service Connection to supply the service principal).

[image: Terraform Step]

To configure the service principal, I am selecting "Manage Service Principal" for the Service Connection.

[image: Service Connection]

I have then given it all "required permissions" for both Microsoft Graph and Windows Azure Active Directory. I don't think I need the Microsoft Graph, but did that since Windows AAD wasn't working.

[image: Service Principal Configuration]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the error information it indicated that you have no permission to do that.

I follow the terraform [guide document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_configuration), we need to assign permissions corrosponding to the application.

> NOTE: If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must have permissions to both **Read and write all applications** and S**ign in and read user profile** within the Windows Azure Active Directory API

During test, I assign the following permission to the Azure Active Diretory, for more information please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Note**： Please don't forget to click **Grant permissions**

**Test Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I struggled with this until i found a comment on a Github Issue about using the Legacy aPI for this, not the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: The link for the guide is a dead link now, any update for that?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_configuration

Answer (score 0):

In order for terraform to access AD and make changes, you need to add these permissions.

[image: listed permission image]

You need to give these permissions to the Service principle of the Azure DevOps service connection. Use Manage Service Principle option. In Azure, these are API permissions for the registered app and its Service Principle.

[image: azure devops service connection image]

More info: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_configuration